# VM: CG raster Data memory keep growing

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management, core-graphics

so i am trying to make an app that will let the user change the color of the UIImage, for that i am using this function i found

```
 - (UIImage *)imageWithTintColor:(UIColor *)color fraction:(CGFloat)fraction
{
    if (color)
    {
        UIImage *image;
        if ([UIScreen instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(scale)])
        {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions([self size], NO, 0.f);
        }
        else
       {
           UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([self size]);
       }

       CGRect rect = CGRectZero;
       rect.size = [self size];
       [color set];
       UIRectFill(rect);

       [self drawInRect:rect blendMode:kCGBlendModeDestinationIn alpha:1.0];

       if (fraction > 0.0)
       {
           [self drawInRect:rect blendMode:kCGBlendModeSourceAtop alpha:fraction];
       }
       image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
       UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
       return image;
   }
   return self;
}
```

everything works but the CG raster Data is growing in memory[image]

Comment: What is the size of image?

Comment: around 200-300kb, and i see those 200, 300 kb...but at the end BAAM 30MB

Comment: what is dimensions size of image? 3000x2000 pixels? Also I assume that this is on iPad simulator?

Comment: image is 1240x1240, yes it is an iPad, but i can show you the specs of an iPhone, still no changes, I heard something about putting  @autoreleasepool but didn't work for me... or i`m not sure where to set it

Comment: The problem can be in other: UIImageView take a lot memory to display big image on big iPad screen

Comment: And also you need profile memory allocation not on simulator (because it is not show real memory usage), but on real device. The results from simulator and real device will be much more different

Comment: for example in my app display 6 UIImageViews 1500x2000 image size take about 150mb on real device, and much more on simulator (about 250mb)

Comment: so there is no way to clear this ?

Comment: For me I don't find any solution yet, but maybe someone have it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, and it was my bad logic, i am using 2 views one to show and one to work with ex:resize, move, rotate. And each time i was addingSubview to both where one of them need to hold just 1 at a time, a simple:

```
  for (UIView *view in 2cndView.subviews)
  {
    [view removeFromSuperview];
  }
```

did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

I have been fighting with my app, that suddenly would not launch properly, for some time now. It turned out that when I had switched a number of images' `Render as` to `Template` in the Image asset file, it caused the app to totally bomb out. `CG Raster Data` was growing exponentially and finally caused the app to stop and Xcode just said

> Lost connection with iPhone.. check connections etc

It would appear that during every launch the images get reprocessed for this 'Template' setting, which consumed a disgusting amount of RAM and actually left it unable to boot. To solve this, I lowered the resolution of the images - as simple as that.